# Filebeat adds unwanted blank fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat

My goal is to collect logs from different servers using Filebeat and aggregate/visualize them using ElasticSearch and Kibana. For the time being, I am excluding Logstash from the scene.

So far I have been able to configure Filebeat to push logs real-time and I am able to confirm through the Kibana interface that the logs are indeed being pushed to ElasticSearch.

**Problem:**

The problem is that the Filebeat (or the ElasticSearch) automatically adds extra empty fields/properties to the index.

Some of the fields I can see on the Kibana interface:

```
aws.cloudtrail.user_identity.session_context.creation_date
azure.auditlogs.properties.activity_datetime
azure.enqueued_time
azure.signinlogs.properties.created_at
cef.extensions.agentReceiptTime
cef.extensions.deviceCustomDate1
cef.extensions.deviceCustomDate2
cef.extensions.deviceReceiptTime
cef.extensions.endTime
cef.extensions.fileCreateTime
cef.extensions.fileModificationTime
cef.extensions.flexDate1
...
```

They are all empty fields.

When I check the mapping for that index using `GET /[index]/_mapping`, I can see ~3000 fields that I didn't really add. I am not sure how these fields were added and how to remove them.

**Reproduction:**

Filebeat and ElasticSearch docker images I use:

```
elasticsearch:7.8.0
elastic/filebeat:7.8.0
```

On top of the base images I put basic configuration files as simple as:

```
# filebeat.yml

filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /path_to/my_log_file/metrics.log

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://192.168.0.1:9200"]
```

```
# elasticsearch.yml

cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0

node.name: node-1

discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1"]

cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]
```

A typical log message would look like this:

```
2020-07-01 08:40:07,432 - CPUUtilization.Percent:50.0|#Level:Host|#hostname:a78f2ab3da65,timestamp:1593592807
2020-07-01 08:40:07,437 - DiskAvailable.Gigabytes:43.607460021972656|#Level:Host|#hostname:a78f2ab3da65,timestamp:1593592807
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the [Elastic Common Schema](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/index.html) (ECS), a [godsend](https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-the-elastic-common-schema)!

When Filebeat starts, it installs an index template with all the ECS fields from the common schema, that's why you see so many fields in your index mapping, but it's not really an issue.

Then, on the Kibana interface you see all those "empty" fields on the Table view (Discover tab). But if you switch to the JSON view, you'll see that those fields are not actually inside the document. Filebeat doesn't add them to your documents. The reason you see them in the Table view is because Kibana is requesting them (using `docvalue_fields`). Just click on Inspect and see the request that Kibana sends to Elasticsearch.

So there's nothing to worry about, really.

Coming to your actual message, if you were to parse `CPUUtilization.Percent:50.0` you could actually store that into a standard ECS field called `"system.cpu.total.pct": 50` and you could see those values evolve over time in the Metrics app in Kibana. Same thing for `DiskAvailable.Gigabytes:43.607460021972656`

Comment: True Addict you are.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The answer already has saved me hours. As suggested in the answer, metrics visualization is indeed my ultimate goal, but I am having trouble finding `system.cpu.total.pct` among the [list of ECS fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/ecs-field-reference.html). I have extracted the value using [Grok processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/grok-processor.html) but simply renaming the field wasn't enough to make it work. Could you see if I am going in the right direction?

Comment: Ok those are actually fields that Metricbeat returns. What you could try to do is in the Metrics app, click on Settings at the top and add your filebeat index at the proper location.

Comment: @Val Thank you for clarification. Charts were automatically created on Metrics app after changing the metrics/settings and using the field names suggested [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/infrastructure/guide/7.4/infrastructure-metrics.html)

Comment: It isn't true that empty fields aren't in doc. They are. I see them in the JSON view. All empty.

Comment: @QkiZ Feel free to create a new question with your exact need. I'm pretty sure we are not talking about the same thing

Comment: Nope, I have the same issue as OP and all these empty fields are in JSON sent by filebeat.

Comment: @QkiZ Can you share that somehow? Maybe through [gist](https://gist.github.com/)?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/QkiZMR/fee9dfac1c51fdce3116cc08497494db

Comment: @QkiZ That's what I thought... What you see in `fields` is not sent by Filebeat, they are `docvalue_fields` as explained in my answer. Filebeat only sends the content of the `_source`.

Comment: So this sentence "But if you switch to the JSON view, you'll see that those fields are not actually inside the document." is wrong because they are in JSON.

Comment: @QkiZ No they are not **inside the document**. The JSON that you see is not the **document**, the document is only what you see inside `_source`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219200/discussion-between-qkiz-and-val).

Answer (score 1):

All the input is being automatically  mapped by filebeat to the 'elastic common schema' aka ECS and exported. Please have a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/exported-fields-ecs.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you define elastic index in filebeat.yml

You can go to Stack Management > Index Management and edit the filebeat index.
In the settings default fields:

```
 "query": {
  "default_field": [
    "message",
    "tags",
    "agent.ephemeral_id",
    "agent.id",
    "agent.name",
    "agent.type",
    ...
    ]}
```

You can remove all the unnecessary fields from here.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own template like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_template/filebeat-7.8.0' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "order" : 1,
    "index_patterns" : [
      "filebeat-7.8.0-*"
    ],
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "lifecycle" : {
          "name" : "filebeat",
          "rollover_alias" : "filebeat-7.8.0"
        },
        "mapping" : {
          "total_fields" : {
            "limit" : "10000"
          }
        },
        "refresh_interval" : "5s"
      }
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "_meta" : {
        "beat" : "filebeat",
        "version" : "7.8.0"
      },
      "date_detection" : false,
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
    "type": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "namespace": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "app": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "k8s-app": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "node": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "pod": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "stream": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
      }
    },
    "aliases" : { }
  }'
```

Explain:

As explained by @Val, Filebeat installs an index template named `filebeat-7.8.0` when it starts. However, if the template exists, Filebeat will use it directly rather than creating a new one. The default value of `setup.template.overwrite` is `false` (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-template.html). By doing this you won't have those fields in your mapping, and Kibana won't show these fields either.